# Variable not working as it should

Tags: php, sql, variables, cookies

Ok, Im baffled.

I am passing in some login info from a cookie and the sql query is rejecting it as not found. Ive done every single test I can think of. var_dumps, data type, etc and everything looks proper. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Im trying to call a login function here and passing in cookies:

```
    if ((isset($_COOKIE["u"]) && empty($_SESSION["user_id"])) || (isset($_COOKIE["u"]) && !isset($_SESSION["user_id"])))
{

    $username = decrypt($_COOKIE["u"], SALT);
    $password = decrypt($_COOKIE["p"], SALT);

    login($username, $password, "1");   

}
```

And the function is:

```
//Log in
function login($username, $password, $remember) {

$userx = query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?", $username);

if (!empty($userx))
{
    $user = $userx["0"];

    if (validate_password($password, $user["hash"]) === true)
    {
    popsession($user, $password, $remember);
    }
    else
    {
    apologize("Invalid Username or Password");
    }
}
else
{
    apologize("Invalid Username or Password");
}

}
```

My issue is happening at $username. When I check it, it all looks good all the way through the process, but when it comes time to query the database it returns nothing. If i replace the variable with a "string" it works fine. To be clear the data type of the variable is a string as well. Any ideas?

Comment: This question's title is almost paradoxic.

Comment: simple, you're not using prepared statements correctly. No preparing and no executing. and if those unknown custom functions are supposed to do that; show them.

Comment: *"Ok, Im baffled."* - Yeah, you and me both, *and then some*.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: My daily laugh thanks to you again hahaha!

Comment: @ChrisG hehe *yet another smiling face*.

Comment: My query function works fine. It preps and executes and error checks as it should, but my issue is that the variable $username, for some reason isnt sending the correct info. I cant figure it out.

Comment: for instance, if I change this: $userx = query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?", $username);      to this:   $userx = query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?", "email@email.com");  it works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PDO, change this:

```
$userx = query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?", $username);
```

To this:

```
$userx = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username");
$userx->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$userx->execute();
```

That should make it work!

Comment: "If you're using PDO", never make assumptions about the question. :)

Comment: True, but it should give a fairly good idea. And it's easily changed to MySQLi aswell :)